# script to detect outliers in a text file

Tags: windows, script

I'm looking for a script which given the following input:

A=0 B=0 C=0
   A=0 B=0 C=0
   A=0 B=0 C=0
   A=0 B=0 C=0.01
   A=0 B=0 C=0
   A=0 B=0 C=2

would output all the lines where the field "C" is not zero, that is:

A=0 B=0 C=2
   A=0 B=0 C=0.01

One way to do it is grep "C=1" | "C=2" | "C=3".. but that's fairly inefficient obviously...

any idea ? this script would be running on windows (cygwin installed). If there is a way to do so involving 3rd party software (eg. excel) then that's of interest too....

Comment: Will the values of `A` and `B` vary as well? If so, can they simply be ignored?

Comment: values of A and B can be ignored... what matters is being able to spot all lines where C is above zero (even if very slightly e.g. C=0.0001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about `grep -v C=0` , here `-v` means in`v`ert, so you will see lines does not include 'C=0'
even without grep, I guess you can use some slightly complex regex to do the same job (not so elegant though).

Comment: You will need to do `grep -v 'C=0$'` to anchor the zero to the end of the line or it will exclude "C=0.01".

Comment: @Dennis  sure. thanks for your graceful complementation.